# Visual Studio changes USERNAME env var

Tags: visual-studio-2005, environment-variables

I'm trying to use the environment variable USERNAME in a Visual Studio 2005 project, but it doesn't seem to work.

In a lone command prompt, USERNAME equates to my user name - i.e. "spfolly"

In a Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt (from the Tools menu), and during a (C++) build, USERNAME equates to " (1 user licence)"

How rude of VS to overwrite my USERNAME environment variable! So, given this situation, what's the best way to find the current username during a build?

Thanks.

Steve

Comment: Doesn't happen for me. What are you exactly doing, and in which order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! Well, I could have deleted the question but I thought I'd leave it here to help others if needed...

It appears that the Visual Lint plug-in (version 1.5.5.69) is the culprit. I uninstalled Visual Link and now USERNAME works as expected.

I realise it's quite an old version; I don't know if the latest version of Visual Lint fixes this problem.